# XFCE panel shows unwanted number of grouped windows

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, 19.10

I have just updated to 19.10. Now XFCE windows panel shows small number in black circle over window icon in the panel that amounts to the number of grouped windows. It is mighty annoying and it looks ugly.

[image]

Is there a setting that I can change to remove that number?

UPDATE: I have filled a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-panel/+bug/1850984

Comment: Indeed, this is something that not everyone likes. There is no setting to turn this off, so it would be worthwhile filing this as an issue.

Comment: @wilx Please answer your question with a description of your issue and a link to the bug report. That's worthy of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a related answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/652948/xfce-how-to-disable-taskbar-items-grouping.

This feature is called as Group Windows by application. In recent version of xfce 4.18, it is given as tick option rather than a drop down in the answer.

Comment: No, it is not. I want grouping without the number or the number should be visually not obstructing the app icon.